# How to change the default date format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I have the following format of date `1.7.2015 19:18` which is `date.month.year` format.

When I convert it into the date variable it is converting as `mm-dd-yy` format.

How can I achieve the format of `dd-mm-yyyy` for the same in JavaScript.

Comment: This question has been asked countless times. Google it before asking a question man!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can try moment.js @ http://momentjs.com/

You can play around with all sort of date functions. Format & Parse the way you want.

moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
will format the current date in this format:
**July 1st 2015, 7:25:03 pm**

Answer (score 0):

If the date value is being retrieved from an input field then you can do something like this:

**Javascript**

```
window.onload = function(){
    var splitted_date = document.getElementById("date").value.split("-"),
        day = splitted_date[1],
        month = splitted_date[0],
        year = splitted_date[2],
        formatted_date = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
};
```